# Ajuda na sintaxe de meu código de repetição FOR

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu quero retornar as porcentagens de gêneros de videogames, só que nessa parte do código não retorna todos os resultados.

```
porcent = pd.DataFrame(base.Genre.unique())

totalPorcGenre = len(base)

for porcen in porcent:
    contagemPorcen = base[base['Genre']==porcen].shape[0]
    print ('Gênero {}: {:0.2f}%'.format(porcen, contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcGenre))
```

```
Resultado:
Gênero 0: 0.00%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, vou te dar 2 abordagens para resolver o problema. A primeira é seguindo a sua lógica, iterando sobre um dataframe. A segundo é utilizando alguns métodos do próprio pandas. Lets go!

### DataFrame de Exemplo

Antes de nos lançarmos na solução, fiz um recorte simples do seu DataFrame para usar de exemplo.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Rank':[1,2,3,4],
        'Name':['Wii Sports', 'Super Mario', 'Mario Kart', 'Wii Sports R'],
        'Genre':['Sports', 'Plataform', 'Racing', 'Sports']}

base = pd.DataFrame(data)
base.head()

#saída
    Rank    Name            Genre
0   1       Wii Sports      Sports
1   2       Super Mario     Plataform
2   3       Mario Kart      Racing
3   4       Wii Sports R    Sports
```

### 1ª solução - Iterando pelo DataFrame

Uilizando a sua lógica de iteração, para iterarmos adequadamente por um DataFrame devemos utilizando um método de iteração, um generator com **iterrows** ou **itertuples**. Este gerador retorna um index e a linha contendo os dados daquela linha, similar ao que o **enum** do python faz. Dessa forma, utilizando a mesma nomenclatura de variáveis, o seu código ficaria dessa forma:

```
porcent = pd.DataFrame(base.Genre.unique())
totalPorcGenre = len(base)

for index, row in porcent.iterrows():
    contagemPorcen = base[base['Genre']==row[0]].shape[0]
    print ('Gênero {}: {:0.2f}%'.format(row[0], contagemPorcen * 100/ totalPorcGenre))

#saída
Gênero Sports: 50.00%
Gênero Plataform: 25.00%
Gênero Racing: 25.00%
```

### 2ª Solução - Utilizando métodos nativos do Pandas

Contudo, não acho que esta seja a melhor abordagem. O Pandas possui uma infinidade de métodos que tornam mais eficiente as manipulações de suas linhas e colunas. Estes métodos são construídos para que não haja iterações/laços otimizando a performance. Em bases com poucas linha é imperceptível, mas em bases maiores, a diferença fica mais evidente. Talk is cheap, show me the code.

```
#No seu código você criou um DataFrame com um único campo para iterar sobre ele.
porcent = pd.DataFrame(base.Genre.unique())

#Ao invés disso, utilizamos o groupby para criar
#um novo DataFrame com uma nova estatística: count
group_genre = pd.DataFrame({'count': base.groupby(['Genre']).size()})
group_genre

#saída

Genre       count   
Plataform   1
Racing      1
Sports      2
```

Após isso, basta adicionar uma nova coluna com a nova métrica de interesse, o percentual de cada Gênero de jogo.

```
count_total = base.shape[0]
count_total

#saída
4

group_genre['percent'] = group_genre['count']/count_total
group_genre

#saída
Genre       count   percent
Plataform   1       0.25
Racing      1       0.25
Sports      2       0.50
```

O interessante dessa abordagem, ao invés de simplesmente iterar, calcular e printar um número na tela, é que você mantêm as suas principais estatísticas de interesse a sua disposição, alocados em memória para continuar a sua exploração, realizando outras manipulações matemáticas ou plotando histogramas e outros diagramas.

Comment: A primeira solução deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda @LeonardoBorges

Comment: Você poderia me explicar o que é parâmetro `axis=None`?

Comment: No pandas, geralmente lidamos com DataFrames (DF) que é um estrutura de dados tipicamente matricial, ou seja, temos linhas e colunas.Neste sentido, quando queremos aplicar alguma operação agregadora neste DF, como por exemplo uma função de média (mean), o pandas vai se perguntar: Devemos aplicar a operação nas linhas ou nas colunas? axis=0 (default) aplica nas linhas. axis=1, aplica nas colunas.

Comment: Fica mais fácil se você pensar como uma tabela em excel. Imagine uma tabela com várias linhas e colunas e você quer a média de todas as linhas, bastaria usar a função mean com axis=0 e teria uma nova linha com a média. Agora com axis=1, você teria uma nova coluna com a média aplicada em todos os valores das colunas.

Comment: E o que seria `Axis=None`?

Comment: Eu particularmente desconheço um método no pandas que utilize axis=None, ou é 0 (default) ou 1. Normalmente métodos que tenham esse argumento (axis) são métodos de agregação (mean, sum, count, etc), ou seja, operam agregando de alguma forma várias linhas ou colunas ao mesmo tempo. E para isso, só faz sentido que você escolher em qual eixo você quer aplicar x ou y. Você conheçe algum método que aceite axis=None?

Comment: O `axis = None`  e `axis= 0` são a mesma coisa (pelo que me parece), retornam o mesmo resultado.

Comment: 0 e None são objetos distintos em python. Precisaria de fazer o teste, mas acredito que se passar None ao invés de zero, teremos um erro. Veja as documentações:
Apply: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
Mean: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html
Sum: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Todas utilizam axis=0 ou 1. Não existe None.

Comment: Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda ai no código, a faculdade esse semestre tá fogo